# Operator inequality $|TS| \leq \|S\|_{B(H)} |T|$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $B(H)$ denote all bounded linear operators.

It is easy to show that $|TS| \leq \|T\|_{B(H)} |S|$ for all $T, S \in B(H)$.
However, does the inequality

$$
|TS| \leq \|S\|_{B(H)} |T|
$$

hold for all $T, S \in B(H)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the $2\times 2$ matrices
$$ T = \pmatrix{1 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr},\ S = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & -1\cr}$$
Now $|T| = T$ because $T$ is positive semidefinite, while
$|TS|$ is the positive semidefinite square root of $(TS)^* TS = \displaystyle\pmatrix{2 & -2\cr -2 & 2\cr}$, namely
$$ |TS| = \pmatrix{1 & -1\cr -1 & 1\cr}$$
and $\|S\| = 1$.
But it is not true that $|TS| \le |T|$.